# Why is the impedance zero at cutoff frequencies in a series RLC resonance circuit?

Tags: capacitor, inductor, frequency, passive-networks, resonance

I see that, in many derivations in the frequency analysis of series RLC circuits, \$X_L - X_c = R\$ or \$Xc - X_L = R\$ is considered at lower and higher cutoff frequencies.
So does that mean that the impedance \$Z = \sqrt{(X_L-Xc)^2 + R^2}\$ is zero at cutoff frequencies?

Comment: Maybe he meant an LC filter, though the terms "minimum" and "cutoff" do confuse things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So does that mean that the impedance (Z = sqrt((Xl-Xc)^2 + R^2)) is
>   zero at cutoff frequencies?

No, your math is wrong.

If \$|X_L - X_C| = R\$ at either of the 3 dB points (cut-off frequencies) then : -

$$Z=\sqrt{R^2 + R^2}$$

or

$$Z=\sqrt2 R$$

Answer (score 1):

The impedance is only zero at the cutoff (resonant) frequency for ideal capacitors and inductors and when R=0.  For real caps and inductors, and when R is not zero, the impedance at resonance may be the minimum, but is not zero.

Answer (score 0):

\$Z_{load}= X_L + X_c + R~~~~~~~~    X_L=jωL,~~ Xc= 1/(jωC)= -j/ωC   \$

\$Z_{load} = j(ωL-1/ωC) + R  \$

\$Z = R ~~~@~ ω=ω_o = 1/\sqrt{LC}\$

\$Q=ω_oL/R  \$

Thus at series resonance the LC reactance nulls to 0  and load reduces to R and attenuation rises to 0 (for ideal source), while current maximizes  to I=V/R as shown below.

[image]

[Sim](http://www.falstad.com/afilter/circuitjs.html?cct=$%200%200.000005%205%2050%205%2050%0A%25%204%2047778.98274364548%0AO%20848%20352%20960%20352%200%0Ag%20848%20400%20848%20432%200%0Al%20848%20304%20848%20240%200%200.0001%200%0A170%20848%20240%20816%20240%203%2020%201000%205%200.1%0Ac%20848%20304%20848%20352%200%200.0001%200%0Ar%20848%20352%20848%20400%200%200.1%0Ao%203%2016%200%2034%205%200.00009765625%200%20-1%0Ao%200%2016%200%2034%205%200.00009765625%201%20-1%0A)

If you move the output between L & C , you see a low pass filter with same peaking factor or Q with voltage gain of 10 due to the impedance ratio of Xc/R at resonance,